# Symfony Doctrine QueryBuilder OneToMany filtering

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, repository

I have following code in my Repository

```
// ProductBundle/Repository/ProductRepository.php

$qb->where($qb->expr()->eq('afp.id', 15));
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('afp.id', 14));

return $qb
            ->select('a', 'afp')
            ->leftJoin('a.productFields', 'afp')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

But I always get null return, but I want to get products which have both productFields (so orWhere is not good).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `MEMBER OF` instead of comparing `id`. Otherwise, you're looking for a record that has two different `id` values, which of course isn't possible.

This will do what you want:

```
$qb->where($qb->expr()->isMemberOf(15, 'a.productFields'));
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->isMemberOf(14, 'a.productFields'));
```

Comment: It doesnt work on first try:  `Attempted to call an undefined method named "isMemberOf" of class "Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr".` I have tried with  `$qb->where("?1 MEMBER OF a.productFields");
        $qb->andWhere("?2 MEMBER OF a.productFields");
        $qb->setParameters(['1' => 14, '2' => 15]);`, but Im stuck

Comment: Ok, that thing works pretty good. Thank You very much for giving me an idea! Now next question is: Is it possible to use `MEMBER OF` for other fields than `id`

Comment: You can pass a whole entity instead of an id, but that does more or less the same thing. If that doesn't do it for you, please consider adding another question and explaining your case in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (Symfony 5):

```
$qb->andWhere(':c MEMBER OF a.productFields');
$qb->setParameter('c', 15);
```